# Continuity like property of Darboux functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am trying to prove a property of Darboux functions. If f is Darboux then there exists sequences ${x_n} \to x^+$ and $y_n \to x^-$ such that $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}f(y_n)$.

My approach was to assume for contradiction, so $f(x_0) \notin \overline{\{f(x): x_0<x \leq x_0 + \delta \}} = E_{\delta}$ for some $\delta$. This implies there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(f(x_0) - \epsilon, f(x_0) + \epsilon) \cap E_{\delta} = \emptyset$. But I am unsure how to use the Darboux property to show that this set cannot be empty.

Thanks

Comment: The $x^-$ case being very similar.

Comment: (1) I think you have a few typos.  For instance, the limits you've written trivially can be false, e.g. $f(x)=x+1$. --- (2) iirc, Darboux functions just satisfy the intermediate value property, right?  In that case, a direct proof is almost certainly easier.

Comment: I'm not sure how the limits are incorrect. $f(x) = x+1$ is continuous and so for any sequence converging to $x$, $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)$. So there certainly exists a sequence.

Comment: You're reading the statement you intended rather than the statement you've written, but the comment does confirm the typo, so I'll fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_1 \in (x_0, x_0  +\delta)$.  Then as $f(x_1) \in E_\delta$, it follows that $f(x_1) \not\in (f(x_0)-\epsilon, f(x_0)+\epsilon)$, so we have either $f(x_1) \geq f(x_0) + \epsilon$ or $f(x_1) \leq f(x_0) - \epsilon$.

Assume $f(x_1) \geq f(x_0) + \epsilon$ (the other case is similar).  Then in particular, $$f(x_0) < f(x_0) + \epsilon/2 < f(x_1)$$
and therefore there will be some $x_2 \in (x_0, x_1)$ such that $f(x_2) = f(x_0) + \epsilon/2$.

Unravel what we've just shown:

- $x_2$ is a point such that $x_0 < x_2 < x_1 < x_0+\delta$ so that $f(x_2) \in E_\delta$
- $f(x_2) = f(x_0) + \epsilon/2 \in (f(x_0)-\epsilon, f(x_0)+\epsilon)$.

Therefore $f(x_2) \in (f(x_0)-\epsilon, f(x_0)+\epsilon) \cap E_\delta = \emptyset$, which is your contradiction.